# How to use .find() to tell if some element has a child or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

for example I have a div `<div id="myrules"></div>`

If i use

```
alert($("#myrules").find("if"))
```

it alerts `[object object]` , even though the div is empty, so the question is how to tell if the child exists or not using `.find()`?

http://jsfiddle.net/prollygeek/agG3d/

Comment: are you looking for child elements or any children including non empty text nodes

Comment: There are countless duplicates; one possible duplicate is [Is there an "exists" function for jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery).

Comment: FWIW, using `console` functions is superior to alert since they are able to print out things like objects and multiple arguments much clearer.  If you used `console.log($('blah')) you would see that what was returned would be an empty "array-like" object since that is what jQuery does is [create a collection  of DOM objects](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery returns a set of matched elements, this set is empty if no elements were selected,
so you need to check against the length property of the returned value.

```
// "length" of the returned collection is 0
if(jQuery('#myelem').find('.idontexist').length)
  alert("element found");
```

Also to be found here:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Comment: I've added an example.

Comment: Ok. Just one thing, that alerts nothing found if something is found.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `$('#myrules').find('if').length`

Answer (score 2):

You can check children of an element like:

HTML

```
<div id="myrules">
    <div class="ch">1</div>
    <div class="ch">2</div>
    <p>3</p>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
alert($("#myrules").children().length) // Alerts total children exists
```

Also you can check specific total children in an element:

```
alert($("#myrules").children('div').length)
alert($("#myrules").children('p').length)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/agG3d/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
alert($($("#myrules").find("#am")).length);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
if($('#myrules').children('div').length > 0){}
```